# Why does the finder refuse to eject SOME of the external drives, saying "finder is using it"?

Tags: finder, external-disk

Some of my external drives (of various types, sizes, and age) can be ejected w/o any issue. Others refuse, saying they can't be ejected because "Finder is using it". I have to close the Finder window and open another window to eject these drives.

Is there any reason--any settings that I can control--why this happens?

Comment: You could open Terminal, find the name of your external drive wit `ls /Volumes/` and then use `sudo lsof | grep /Volumes/DRIVE` where DRIVE is the name of your external drive to see which processes are actually using the drive.

Comment: I appreciate the editors' link to the similar question. But I hope editors understand that without knowing the key terms "locked volume", one cannot find a solution (including that similar question). So I believe my question has merit. You can close it, but I hope you let others see it, so they can find the suggested link.